# Is it can also be explained by CLT?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, central-limit-theorem, time-series

```
w = exprnd(10,[1,10000000]);
x1 = conv(w,ones(1,100)/10,'same')+10; 
histogram(w);
figure;
histogram(x1);
```

Above the MATLAB code,

I generated the many samples, $w$,  from exponential distribution.

from $w$, I made **correlated samples**, $x1$ by using LPF convolution.

When getting the histogram of $x1$, it looks **Gaussian**, surprisingly.

How can I explain it?

To the best of my knowledge, CLT is about the sum of RVs with IID or not.

However in this case, it is about the correlated time-series.

Could you give me a little intuition?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: This convolution is basically taking the sum of a bunch of the exponentials (a weighted sum, but the effect is the same). This is just the CLT in action.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen After seeing your comment, I changed the length of LPF. After that, its shape become far from the Gaussian. As you said, the sum of convolution make this Gaussian. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, if there is less smoothing, then the distribution will be less normal. In case this is what you're really interested in, there are ways of generating correlated random variables where you have full control over their marginal distribution. e.g. we could get an autocorrelated sequence of exponentials if that is what you want.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but if you are interested in seeing more interesting kinds of correlated samples, a better way to do it is by forming a matrix with iid Gaussian entries and takings the eigenvalues (there are many variants of this, you can also generate an iid Gaussian symmetric or Hermitian matrix, etc)